# Node.js PM2: programmatically retrieving all process IDs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, pm2

I'm trying to programmatically get an array of all of the PM2 process IDs in cluster mode.

```js
const pm2 = require("pm2");

let allPids;

async function getPids() {
    return await new Promise(resolve => {
        pm2.list((err, list) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                resolve(list.map(process => process.pid));
            }
        });
    });
}

getPids().then(pids => {
    console.log(pids); // outputs an array of PIDs
    allPids = pids;
});

console.log(allPids); // outputs undefined
```

The above code successfully gets all of the PIDs with `pm2.list()`, but I'm unable to access them outside of the `.then()` callback.

```js
const pm2 = require("pm2")

let pids;

pm2.list((err, list) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        pids = list.map(process => process.pid);
    };
});

console.log(pids); // outputs undefined

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(pids); // outputs array of PIDs
}, 1000);
```

This code also worked, but only in the `setTimeout()` callback.

The PM2 [documentation](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-api/) was no help whatsoever.

Is there a way access the PIDs without placing all of my code in the `.then()`/`setTimeout()` callback? Or, is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your function is async, so why not `await`?

```
const pm2 = require("pm2");

let allPids;

async function getPids(): number[] {
 
    let pids = [];

    try {
      pids = await pm2.list();
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }

    return list.map(process => process.pid);
}

(async () => {
   allPids = await getPids();
   console.log(allPids);
})();
```

Comment: `await` can't be used outside an async function.

Comment: I have updated my answer. An anonymous function will allow this.

Comment: That works, but isn't any better than just placing all of my code in the `.then()`. I was hoping to avoid that, but it's fine if it's not possible.

Comment: Shrug. You asked "Is there a way access the PIDs without placing all of my code in the .then()/setTimeout() callback? Or, is there a better solution?" This answers both questions. 1) There are no `.then` or timeouts 2) It is better because it is far more readable.